# When to use "^" operator

Tags: c#

What is the operator below **^**?
When to use it?

My programing language is C#.

Comment: Google, or MSDN in this case, is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1%28VS.71%29.aspx. To answer your 2nd question, you use the operator when you need it, just like e.g. the `+` operator.

Comment: Google is not an answer, MSDN, however, is. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: If he doesn't know what he's looking for, Googling can be hard, especially since Google doesn't even recognize the ^ character.  Plus, he also wants to know "when to use it" something no place could answer better than StackOverflow

Comment: What *I* want to know is, when do I use the ^_^ operator?

Comment: @Neil N: Knowing that `^` is an operator, and that it's about the C# language, and that the language is from Microsoft, and that Microsoft's developer platform is known as MSDN, one can search for `MSDN C# operators`. That's how I ended up at the page linked to in the above comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`^` is a **Logical XOR Operator** if the operands are bools, otherwise it's a **Bitwise XOR Operator**

> Binary ^ operators are predefined for the integral types and bool. For integral types, ^ computes the bitwise exclusive-OR of its operands. For bool operands, ^ computes the logical exclusive-or of its operands; that is, the result is true if and only if exactly one of its operands is true.
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx

Comment: "Logical XOR operator."  - That's only true if the operands are bools, otherwise it's a bitwise operator.  Playing fast-and-loose with the terms 'bitwise' and 'logical' makes life very hard when you come to explain the difference between & and && in 'C'...

Answer (score 3):

It's the [XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) operator.  It's used in bitwise operations, where the result is true if the left side is true *or* the right side is true, but false if *both* are true or *both* are false.  So `0xf8 ^ 0x3f` would be:

```
1111 1000
0011 1111
---------
1100 0111
```

Which is C7 in hexadecimal.

In general, if you're not doing bitwise arithmetic, you won't need to worry about it.

Comment: You forgot to add that it's also false if BOTH are false.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

- It is often used as a way to "flip
  bits" by XORing it with 1 (to flip),
  0 (to keep). Usually this is useful
  in encryption/decryption/hashing. ** THIS IS ACTUALLY USEFUL **

Example:

```
101 ^  
110  
-----
011   //Flip the first 2, keep the 3rd
```

- It can also be used for a swapping
  method (though, using the standard
  way and generics is probably more ideal):

Example:

```
int myMoney = 10;
int yourMoney = 50;
Swap(myMoney, yourMoney)

public void Swap(ref int a, ref int b) //No 'temp' variable necessary
{
  a ^= b;
  b ^= a;
  a ^= b;
}
```

- It is used in binary arithmetic. ** THIS IS ACTUALLY USEFUL **
- Flip a bool (though, I'd rather use bool x = true; x != x;

Example:

```
public bool flip(ref bool b)
{
    b ^= true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think of it as a binary operator just like ||, &&, etc...

If I were writing logic and ended up with:

```
if( (condition1 && !condition2) || (condition2 && !condition1) )
{
}
```

I might rewrite it as:

```
if( condition1 ^ condition2)
{
}
```

That said, I'd take it on a case by base basis and weigh the benefit of brevity vs. potential obfuscation due to relative obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

Its Exclusive OR (XOR) operator as mentioned by others. Here is the truth table for XOR

```
P    Q    P^Q
T    T     F
T    F     T
F    T     T
F    F     F
```

Note that P^Q is equal to P!=Q. Sometimes P!=Q is used in the code instead of XOR operator.